# Read multiple CSV files in Azure ML Python Script

Tags: python, csv, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have 4 csv files that are inputs to the python script in azure ML, but the widget has only 2 inputs for dataframes and the third for a zip file. I tried to put the csv files in a zipped folder and connect it to the third input for the script but that also did not work :
[image: Image of workspace]

I would like to know how to read multiple csv files in the python script.

Comment: would appending all csv files into one be an option? This can be done easily with Python. Sort of a pre-process thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some more detail on the approach others have outlined above. Try replacing the code currently in the "Execute Python Script" module with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
def azureml_main(dataframe1=None, dataframe2=None):
    print(os.listdir('.'))
    return(pd.DataFrame([]))
```

After running the experiment, click on the module. There should be a "View output log" link now in the right-hand bar. I get something like the following:

```
[Information]         Started in [C:\temp]
[Information]         Running in [C:\temp]
[Information]         Executing 4af67c05ba02417a980f6a16e84e61dc with inputs [] and generating outputs ['.maml.oport1']
[Information]         Extracting Script Bundle.zip to .\Script Bundle
[Information]         File Name                                             Modified             Size
[Information]         temp.csv                                       2016-05-06 13:16:56           52
[Information]         [ READING ] 0:00:00
[Information]         ['4af67c05ba02417a980f6a16e84e61dc.py', 'Script Bundle', 'Script Bundle.zip']
```

This tells me that the contents of my zip file have been extracted to the `C:\temp\Script Bundle` folder. In my case the zip file contained just one CSV file, `temp.csv`: your output would probably have four files. You may also have zipped a folder containing your four files, in which case the filepath would be one layer deeper. You can use the `os.listdir()` to explore your directory structure further if necessary.

Once you think you know the full filepaths for your CSV files, edit your Execute Python Script module's code to load them, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/temp/Script Bundle/temp.csv')
    # ...load other files and merge into a single dataframe...
    return(df)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As @MattR said, you just need to directly append the 4 csv files into the zip file `theano_keras2.zip`, without package these csv files as an alone zip file to append. Then you can use these csv files in the module `Execute Python Script`, that the csv file path is relative to the root of the directory of `theano_keras2.zip`.

Hope it helps.